# how python circuits components loading process works

Tags: circuits-framework

python circuits is a great framework, I am not familiar with its component
loading machanism

apart from loads from the /site-data folder for installed python modules through pip, I guess thats where the PYTHONPATH is set

is it loads from else where? e.g the current path when I do invoke python app.py?

Answer (score 0):

It uses [safe_import](https://github.com/circuits/circuits/blob/master/circuits/core/utils.py#L52) which ultimately uses `__import__` from the Python builtins. This means your components have to be importable via the normal Python import paths.